# Dynamic class name in Batman.js view

Tags: javascript, jquery, batman.js

My question is very close to [Setting id and className dynamically in Backbone.js views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7033134/setting-id-and-classname-dynamically-in-backbone-js-views), but for batman.js.
In batman there are `data-addclass` method, but I need something like this:

```
<span data-class="item.color"></span>
```

What will produce for example:

```
<span class="yellow"></span>
```

What is the best practice to perform such things in batman.js? Maybe I should use `data-bind` and detect class with jquery?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The easiest way to do that would be to just perform a `data-bind-` directly onto the attribute you would like to change, in this case `class`.

```
<span data-bind-class="someBatmanVariable">Here is my content</span>
```

Where `someBatmanVariable` is just something you've set up in the controller which resolves to the class you'd like the `span` to have.

You can take it further and put whatever you'd like just about anywhere. You can bind to most attributes and they'll update. Don't forget that by not specifying an attribute (a vanilla `data-bind`) Batman will default to something logical, usually the contents of the tag or, in the case of `input` elements, the `value`.

Finally, be sure to take a look at the [Batman view filters](http://batmanjs.org/docs/batman.html#batman-view-filters). You can massage the output quite a bit.

Comment: Thank you for extended answer. `data-bind-class` - it is what I looking for.
My bad, next time I should read documentation more carefully :) PS batman is awesome :)

Comment: Hey Fletch, welcome to Stack Overflow.  It'd be awesome if you could edit and clean up your answer so that your final answer is clearer.

Comment: Good idea smathy! I rewrote it to cut to the chase.