# Unable to change the tagName of model in Backbone

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I am trying to set the `tagName` for the model I am creating but it not working. There is no errors in the console and it works but the tag is `div` without any class, id or attribute that is specified in the model.

Please help.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  // NOTE: Basic Model of template
  var ZcoBuilderModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    tagName :  "span",
    className: "zco_builder_element",
    id : "1233",
    attributes : {
      "data-type": "template"
    },
    defaults: {
      en_header: false,
      en_title: false,
      en_Content: false,
      en_Footer: false,
      en_deletable: false,
      title: "",
      en_template_status: false,
      id_header : 0,
      id_title: 0,
      id_Content: 0,
      id_Footer: 0,
    },
    initialize: function() {
      console.log("Created");
    }
  });

  // NOTE: Collaction of templates
  var ZcoBuilderCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: ZcoBuilderModel
  });

  // NOTE: View template for Single Model
  var ZcoBuilderView = Backbone.View.extend({
    render: function() {
      var zcoBuilderTemplate = _.template($('#zcoTemplate').html());
      var zcoBuilderTemplateHTML = zcoBuilderTemplate(this.model.toJSON());
      this.$el.html(zcoBuilderTemplateHTML);
      return this;
    }
  });

  // NOTE: View Template for Collection Model this will render above
  var ZcoBuilderViewCollection = Backbone.View.extend({
    render: function() {
      var self = this;

      this.model.each(function(e) {
        var n = new ZcoBuilderView({
          model: e
        });
        self.$el.append(n.render().$el);
      });
    }
  });

 // NOTE: defaults collection
  var zcoBuilderDefaults = new ZcoBuilderCollection(
    [
      new ZcoBuilderModel({
        title: "Global"
      }),
    ]
  );

  //Templates Rendering
  var zcoBuilder = new ZcoBuilderViewCollection({
    el: '#zco_list',
    model: zcoBuilderDefaults
  });
  $('#zco_list').html(zcoBuilder.render());


});
```

Comment: Is this what u r looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/a/36018794/7057771. Pardon me, if I'm wrong. I'm new to backbonejs

Comment: @Yahiya thank you . Just a second ago I found my answer. ZcoBuilderView should have the tagName property. So far enjoying it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Properties like `tagName`, `id`, `className`, `el`, and `events` have a [special meaning](https://backbonejs.org/#View-extend) when using in a `View`, but there are useless for the `Model`

Move it from `ZcoBuilderModel` to `ZcoBuilderView`